# deletesubkeytree not deleting registry folder

Tags: c#, registry, directory

I want to delete a folder named EXAMPLE and all values in it in registry that is found under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE"

i have tried this ( with true at the end aswell )

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE");
```

and tried this

```
string keyName = @"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
{
    key.DeleteSubKeyTree("EXAMPLE", true);
}
```

They either throw me a null exception or argument exception. 
How can i just delete an entire folder with all its keys ? 
So that i can have the similar effect from batch : 
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE" /f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is incorrect, `Registry.LocalMachine` doesn't have such a sub key `@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\..."`. You need to start from `"SOFTWARE\.."`.

```
string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
```

And from your feedback, your program is affected by the [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/registry-redirector), in which `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` is redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node` for a 32-bit program, recompile your program from `AnyCPU (Prefer 32-bit)` to `x64` gets rid of the redirection.

The mechanism of `Registry Redirector` varies on different Windows versions, so I leave this to you for further reading to understand why 64/32 matters in this case.

Comment: i tried @"SOFTWARE already but it throws an argument exception saying the subkey doesnt exist, even know the folder "EXAMPLE" is there.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by registry redirection, you need to compile your program as x64, not AnyCPU.

Comment: Glad I can help, I also add some explanation on the x64 for you.